# Compact code for different lay out of disabled Angular Material buttons

Tags: css, angular, if-statement, angular-material

I've been wondering if there's any easy way to change the lay out of a **disabled** button from Angular Material.

Right now, I do it using a ng-container and a ng-template. This works fine, but as you can see the code is not very compact because the only difference between the two buttons (in essence) is `class="disabled"` and this class should only be used if the button is disabled. I know there's more difference than just that but that's because I just removed (click) etc. for the disabled button since it isn't used anyway. Same goes for the disabled property on the non-disabled button, there's no point in having it.

```
                <ng-container *ngIf="disabledNext; else next">
                    <button mat-button class="disabled" type="button" [disabled]="disabledNext">
                        Next
                    </button>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-template #next>
                    <button mat-raised-button (click)="nextDate()" type="button">
                        Next
                    </button>
                </ng-template>
```

**I'm looking for an answer along the lines of this** but I'm not sure if that's possible

```
<button mat-button-raised class="disabledNext ? disabled : ''">Next</button>
```

**OR** some kind of CSS selector that works if the disabled property of the button is `true`

```
button.disabled { ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Conditionally set classes using `[class.classname]="condition"` syntax
2. Conditionally set disabled using `[attr.disabled]="condition ? true : null"`

If the button is disabled, the click handler shouldn't fire, but you could always exit the handler early if the button is set to disabled.

Note: the button will be disabled if `disabled` attribute is present - even an empty string. Using the `null` value for the enabled state means the attribute won't get added to the HTML.

```html
<button [class.disabled]="disabled" type="button" 
    [attr.disabled]="disabled ? true : null" (click)="nextDate()">
  Next
</button>
```

This is a demo for pure Angular.

You can conditionally add the `mat-raised-button` class if not disabled.

```html
<button mat-button [class.mat-raised-button]="!disabled">
</button>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e8gkca